# Variable not emptied in batch script after set to empty

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script which is supposed to ping a site, log the results, and start a program if the results were negative. This is a modification of original script (not mine), which can be found [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/511-connection-checker). Values of domain, IP, and program variables are for illustrative purposes.

```
@echo off
cls

set domain=testsite.com
set IP=133.78.17.101
set program=c:\windows\notepad.exe
set output=c:\log.txt
set result=1

:Start
IF [%result%]==[] (
    >>%output% echo -----------
    start %program%
)
ECHO Pinging %domain%...
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('ping -n 1 %domain% ^| find "Reply"') DO SET result=%%G
IF NOT [%result%]==[] (
    goto Success
) ELSE (
    goto TryAgain
)

:TryAgain
ECHO %domain% unreachable. Trying again...
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('ping -n 1 %domain% ^| find "Reply"') DO SET result=%%G
IF NOT [%result%]==[] ( 
    goto Success2
) ELSE (
    goto TryIp
)

:TryIp
ECHO %domain% unreachable. Pinging %ip%...
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('ping -n 1 %IP% ^| find "Reply"') DO SET result=%%G
IF NOT [%result%]==[] (
    goto SuccessDNS
) ELSE (
    goto TestInternet
)

:TestInternet
ECHO %ip% unreachable. Testing internet connection.
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('ping -n 1 www.google.com ^| find "Reply"') DO SET result=%%G
IF NOT [%result%]==[] (
    goto Success3
) ELSE (
    goto NetDown
)

:Success
>>%output% ECHO Connected
>>%output% echo %date% %time% %result%
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto Start

:Success2
>>%output% ECHO Connected with packet loss.
>>%output% echo %date% %time% %result%
set result=
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto Start

:Success3
>>%output% ECHO Domain %domain% not reachable. Connected via IP.
>>%output% echo %date% %time% %result%
set result=
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto Start

:SuccessDNS
>>%output% ECHO DNS problem.
>>%output% echo %date% %time% %result%
set result=
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto Start

:NetDown
>>%output% ECHO No internet connection.
>>%output% echo %date% %time% %result%
set result=
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto Start
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this - if anything other than a perfect reply to a ping request is received, the script should start a program. To secure that this happens only then, I've been clearing the `result` variable every time, other than on an expected ping response.

Echoing the value of `result` keeps returning 1, even after I've emptied it.

Comment: `%result%` and `%result` is not the same. You have a typo the  `IF NOT [%result]==[] (` lines.

Comment: Change all instances of `%result` for `%result%` and try again!

Comment: @Stephan Right, corrected it, but still not working as I expect it to.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hm, but I don't want to clear it if it's a success - if I did clear it, it would start the `program`. I want to start it only if the ping didn't work on the first try, and to keep starting it every time that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your line

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %domain% ^| find "Reply"') DO SET result=%%G
```

`%%G` is either not defined (when the word `Reply` doesn't occur), which doesn't touch your `Result` variable at all,
or a line like `Reply from x.x.x.x : Bytes=32 Time<1ms TTL=128`, which definitively isn't empty.
According to the rest of your code, you probably meant `... DO SET "result="` to unset the variable.

Note: searching for "Reply" is
a) language dependent ("Antwort" on German Windows) and
b) not reliable (think of `Reply from localhost: destination address unreachable`).
Better search for `TTL=` (even works without a `for` loop):

```
ping -n 1 %IP% | find "TTL=" >nul && set "reply=true" || set "reply=false"
echo %reply%
```

Comment: Actually, `DO SET result=%%G` is in the code because I needed to log `result` to a file with `>>%output% ECHO (%result%`. But still, you make a very good point about `result` not being changed / defined if there's no `Reply` (or TTL, as you suggested). That's one of the reasons the code wasn't working as I'd expect it to. Thanks, for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to [Stephan's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46284294/6133426).

In addition to reasons posted in Stephan's post, the code was not working as I had originally planned it to, because the comparisons were failing as well. If there was a successful ping, the `result` variable was being set to a string consisting of multiple words, which was breaking the comparison. To avoid this, I had to change every instance of

```
IF [%result%]==[]
```

to

```
IF ["%result%"]==[""]
```

Thomas Weller's (now deleted) comment was also on the right track - I **did** need to empty the `result` variable in `:Start`:

```
:Start
IF ["%result%"]==[""] (
    >>%output% echo -----------
    start %program%
)
SET result=
ECHO Pinging %domain%...
```

This emptying was needed to annul any previous successes and the original `set result=1` (in case of consistent failures).